# Making a ggplot Choropleth Map with Interactive Labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, r-plotly

Is there any feasible way to take the code I have here in ggplot and convert it in such a way that would make the labels appear when I hover over the map in R Studio?

It's a choropleth map of the USA with 3 digit zips as a label:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_cartogram(data = mymap, aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = id), map = mymap) + 
  geom_cartogram(data = myframe, aes(fill = value, map_id = group), map = mymap) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral"))) + 
  coord_map() + 
  theme_map()
```

Comment: Try `my_plot <-  [your ggplot text above];   library(plotly);  ggplotly(my_plot)`

Comment: Thanks, just tried that and got this message: Warning messages:
1: In geom2trace.default(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]], dots[[3L]][[1L]]) :
  geom_GeomCartogram() has yet to be implemented in plotly.
  If you'd like to see this geom implemented,
  Please open an issue with your example code at
  https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues

Comment: Is there a possible workaround to this? Otherwise I'll open the issue

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible? This might help https://plot.ly/r/choropleth-maps/